# How to acknowledge messages in Message Driven Beans

Tags: java, jms, message-driven-bean

In the JMS documentation I read that Message Driven Beans doesn't support `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` mode, only `DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE` and `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE`.

As I understand it, in `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` mode, the message is acknowledged (deleted from the destination) when the onMessage method is invoked. What I want is to tell my broker not to delete messages from the destination (queue or topic) when something bad happens

There must be some way to do this. Anyway, why is `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` not supported in Message Drven Beans.

Comment: AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE deletes the message *after* onMessage is successfully called

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What I want is to tell my broker not to delete messages from the
>   destination (queue or topic) when something bad happens.

If you're configured to use `PERSISTENT` messages, any exceptions in `onMessage()` will persist the message for redelivery based on broker and destination settings. If you're using `NON_PERSISTENT` messages, any exception in `onMessage()` typically discards the message.

> Anyway, why is CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE not supported in Message Driven Beans.

Message-driven beans are managed by the J2EE container; as such, the container handles acknowledgements. Typically, only stand-alone JMS receivers should use `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`.

What messaging middleware are you using?

Comment: This is exactly the information I found out today researching. :) But thanks anyway! I use OpenMQ on Glassfish server.

Comment: "any exceptions in onMessage() will persist the message for redelivery " -- should I throw the exception in onMessage? But I cannot because onMessage method is implemented and it doesn't throw the exception.

Comment: @NoorSyed That's a problem because once `onMessage()` completes successfully, it's consumed.

Comment: Persistence settings are for handling failures ( infra structure or JMS/Application server crashes). They are NOT about redelivery after an exception is thrown from application code

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you are using (JTA) transactions (the default is that you are using them). Then make sure your applications server has a redelivery setting and or a Dead Letter Queue (DLQ). Any exceptions thrown from your MDB will then trigger a redelivery and after a certain amount of failures the message will be moved to the DLQ.

The redeilvery setting is called "max-delivery-attempts" in Wildfly for instance

Answer (score 0):

In Mdb you can tell the broker to not delete the message trough 'MessageDrivenContext'. (Without throwing exception - which also rollbacks the transaction)

Some example code, Where you can handle all exceptions in method 'onMessaage' and set a rollback in case of Exception:

```
@MessageDriven(name = "queueMDB", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "TestQueue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
}
public class TestMdb implements MessageListener {

    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext messageDrivenContext;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            // Some usefull code...
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            messageDrivenContext.setRollbackOnly();
        }
    }
}
```